# How to avoid arrays in relational database?

Tags: sql, arrays, database, rdbms

My database describes companies websites. A company website has several attribute: URL, load time, etc. Each website is targeting one or several countries. I have problems expressing the relation between the website and the countries.

My setup number 1 looks like this:

- A Company table
- A Country table
- A Website table, with fields WebsiteId, CompanyId (refers to Company.id), Countries (array referring to Country.id) and several attributes like URL, LoadTime, etc.

My setup number 2 looks like this:

- A Company table
- A Country table
- A Website table, with fields WebsiteId, CompanyId (refers to Company.id) and several attributes like URL, LoadTime, etc.
- A WebsiteCountries table, with fields WebsiteId, CountryId

I have problem with both approaches:

- Setup number 1 uses an array of Country.id, which makes it hard to maintain
- In setup number 1, CompanyId has a unique constraint in the Website table, but allows duplicate in setup number 2. More generally, CompanyId + Countries could act as a candidate key in setup 1. This disturbs me a bit : am I wrong and is it the best approach?

Comment: "setup number 2" is right, Just have unique constraint on `WebsiteId` **and** `CountryId`, This could be a primary key.

Comment: Use PostgreSQL, Luke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Jodrell already gave you the correct answer - "setup number 2" with compound PK is the best solution. I'll just explain it in details.

There are companies, countries and websites. For each of them we create a separate table.

Now it's time for references:

- If a company may have only one website, then it's one-to-one relationship. If it may have many websites, then it's one-to-many relationship. In both cases you have a foreign key CompanyId in Website table - it'll only differ in UNIQUE constraint.
- You write "Each website is targeting one or several countries." Additionally, for every country there may be one or more websites (for different companies). It means that it's a classical many-to-many relationship. In such case you must add a junction table - WebsiteCountries. Here you'll have a compound primary key that constists of two columns: (WebsiteId, CountryId). This'll prevent from duplicates.

Hope this helps.